# How to keep HTML input tag value

Tags: html, jquery

[image]
[image: after hit enter, the label disappears]

```
<input id= "{{ label.id }}" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { label(this.id, this.value);alert(event); }" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="label name" autofocus></input>
```

Once I hit the submit button (not shown in the pic), the input (from the pic above), ***test***, will disappear. How should I change so that after I click the submit button, the input will still stays in?

My JS

```
<script>
var label = function(id, name) {
   console.log(id);
   console.log(name);
   window.location.replace("/label/" + id + "?name=" + name);
}
</script>
```

Backend

```
@app.route('/label/<id>')
def label(id):
   name = request.args.get("name")
   #app.config["LABELS"][int(id) - 1]["name"] = name
   session['labels'][int(id) - 1]["name"] = name
   return redirect(url_for('tagger'))
```

Comment: Input text does not disappear on it's own when you submit a form - [see this simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/a1unw9k6/). So something in your code is disappearing it. The JS you have shown will call a function `label()` when you hit return (which is not the same as when you submit, btw).  So, what does `label()` do?

Comment: Unless you are talking about after the form being submitted, the browser loading the same page again? In that case yes, it is a "new" page, and the previous input which has just been POSTed to your server is not in the current request.  If you want to access it again, you either need your backend to return it with the page content, or use cookies, sessions, etc. Or use JS to stop the actual submission in the first place, and just use the values that were entered without POSTing them anywhere.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you for the reply. I updated my question with my JS and backend code. I'm still not sure where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
... onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { label(...); }"
```

means that when you hit enter in that input, the `label()` function will be called.  Looking at `label()`, this line:

```
window.location.replace("/label/" + id + "?name=" + name);
```

means the browser will be redirected to a new page.  [`replace()` means the current page will be *replaced*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) with the specified one, and the current one will not be preserved in browser history.

In this case it means when you hit enter in that input field, the browser will redirect to a new page.  The form was not submitted, you simply browsed away to a new page.  If you hit back, you will not get back to the page where that form was.

Note the current code reacts to hitting enter, which is not the same as submitting the form.  If you click a submit button, this code does nothing.   If instead you want to handle the form submission, whether by mouse click or keyboard, you need to listen for the form `submit` event.

You haven't shown us your form HTML, so let's say it looks like this:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="{{ label.id }}" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

I've given the form an `id`, we can target that with a selector.  I've also removed the inline JS from the `input`.  The `input` has a dynamic `id` so a selector for it is a little trickier.  For now let's just assume it is the only input on the form.

Best practice is to keep your JS and HTML separate, so rather than writing inline JS with the `input` like `onkeydown()`, have it separate:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(event) {
    // Form was submitted!  Do stuff.
    alert('submitted!');

    // Stop normal form submission, we are handling it in JS
    event.preventDefault();

    // Retrieve info about the inputs.  First let's find the input, 
    // remember this assumes there is only 1 on the form.
    var $input = $('input');

    // Now we can pull info about that input
    var id = $input.attr('id');
    var value = $input.val();
    alert('input id is: ' + id + ', value is: ' + value); 

    // You could call your label() function here if you want,
    // though in its current state that will just navigate away
    // so that's probably not what you want.
    // label(id, value);
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle of that code](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/bqpvgz1L/) to test and experiment with.

If you have more than one input on the form, and you need to target them individually, you'll need to use a different selector than just the  `$('input')` I used.  If this JS is on the same page as the HTML itself, ie not in a separate `.js` file, you could simply use the same code that you've used in the HTML:

```
var $input = $('#' + {{ label.id }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the value in a variable through the request input, pass it to the view and show it in value =" "

Answer (score 0):

Declare your submit button using `button` tag and add the function explicitly.

```js
document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click',function(){
/*Describe what You want to do Here*/
    alert('hai');
});
```

```css
#input-box{
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:20px;
  width:300px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-box"/>
<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```